# how to fix Hebrew font in Chrome browser after installing Windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, hebrew

Yesterday I installed Windows 10, and then My Hebrew on Google Chrome went crazy. Please see image attached.

Hope to get help soon.

Many thanks,
Ofer.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: Also, uh, your picture appears to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

had a similar problem.
fixed with:
entering "about:flags" in the address line
and then enable "direct write"